# Google Chrome keep me logged out if I open dev console

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, adonis.js

I am facing a very strange problem in my node application (built with adonis.js). It was working all ok but now in other browser it works. But if I login it works but as soon as I open dev console it log me out.

My app is running on `http://localhost:8181/`. I tried with changing port but it same.

I don't know what more information I should share.

Many thanks.

Comment: how about if you build the app?

Comment: Have you tried network tab --> disable cache? It's a stretch and I don't know if it could be causing problems here but it's worth a try.

Comment: `disable cache` doesn't have any effect. But I found why its happening.

Answer (score 0):

OK so I am posting it for others as it may help.

I am using adonis js. It has a authentication policy in session file as `sameSite` by default it was true for these days and was working. Now in chrome, `sameSite: true` doesn't work. So making it `false` works.

Strange why this happening. It is also happening in my old built application.